# what does 1: mean in the verb train (100 $ - {. 1:)"0

Tags: j

the j solution to the [100 doors problem in rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/100_doors#J) is `~:/ (100 $ - {. 1:)"0 >:i.100`

`>: i. 100` means 'make a list of numbers from 1 to 100'

`(100 $ - {. 1:)"0 >: i. 100` means 'make a list of 100 lists, where each position represents an integer, and make every nth position 1'

`~:/ (100 $ - {. 1:)"0 >: i. 100` means 'turn on only the numbers that have a one in their column only once' which are the squares.

but the verb train `(100 $ - {. 1:)` has me mystified... What does `1:` mean? I found the `:` verb in [nuvoc](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/tildeco), but I did not see this specific application there. How are the verbs grouped?

Comment: It seems that `(100 $ - {. 1:)` is a [monadic noun fork] [https://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/forks_hooks_and_compound_adv.htm], and that `- {. 1:` provides the list of numbers with which to fill the 100 rows of the `100 $` plane.

Comment: The verb `1:` simply produces a scalar integer `1` for any and all inputs, monad or dyad. Similarly `2:` produces a `2`, `_7:` produces a `_7`; these are all verbs defined in the dictionary as effectively convenience functions. There are 19 of them; from `_9:` through `0:` to `9:` (ie all single-digit decimal integers). It’s not some kind of `:` function applied to a literal numeric constant. Thus, the fork `$ {. 1:` produces a list of `n=. $y` booleans, with one leading `1` (produced by `1:`) and `n-1` trailing zeros, per the definition of `{.`.

Comment: @DanBron thanks! if you put this as answer and link to the place in the docs where they explain this, I will gladly accept it : )

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that. Sadly, I’m on the mobile app which is unfortunately no longer supported. So it has some constraints. I can’t paste links anymore, for example. And editing answers is a PITA. But feel free to post it yourself. You needn’t even credit me. Just go to Jsoftware, find the NuVoc, and search for `0:`. You’ll find the link. Alternatively, wait just a bit and the expert and generous other J community members are sure to post formal and helpful answers.

Comment: you are very kind :)  I'll give someone else in the community a chance to get the rep. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh! I lied. I was focused on `$ {. 1:` for some reason: the actual train is `100 $ - {. 1:`; the concept is still the same expect now instead of `n=. $y` it’s `n=.-y`, thus the `1` produced by the verb `1:` is *trailing*, not *leading*, and then `100 $ ..` ensures the resultant array’s length is exactly 100, truncating or repeating elements (cyclically) as require to achieve that specific length. Sorry for the mid-up.

Comment: that's ok. Your first answer still taught me a lot, given how much of a n00b I'm at J